# How can I close a program if a different program is already running?

Tags: batch-file

Can I use a batch file to determine if a program is running or open and, if it is, close a different program?

For example, how could I check to see if `game.exe` is running and, if it is, then close `google.exe`?

Comment: You could maybe use tasklist to get a list of processes, then look if the game.exe appears in the output, if yes start taskkill /im google.exe /f.

Comment: and if you cant can you with some other language

Comment: can you show me what it would look like

Comment: In vbscript it can be done easily, just edit your question and add the vbscript tag and i will show an example ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617380/vbscript-how-can-you-see-if-a-programes-open-then-close-it here hackoo

Answer (score 0):

```
@For /f "Delims=:" %A in ('tasklist /v /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq New Folder"') do @if %A==INFO (
    echo Prog not running
) else (
    taskkill /im program.exe /f
)
```

Also see for /?. You may want to pipe through findstr to clean it up a bit.