# vbscript how can you see if a program is open then close it

Tags: vbscript

How can I use vbscript to determine if a program is running or open and, if it is, close a different program?

For example, how could I check to see if game.exe is running and, if it is, then close google.exe?

Comment: What did you tried so far ? can you post your code ? and what's the relationship between game.exe and google.exe
Did you mean google.exe = Chrome.exe ???

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that show you how to check a process by name and if the check is positive so it kill it.

For example i choose the Game as **Calc.exe** and if the script found it, it will be killed, and also for **internet explorer** and **Google Chrome**

```
Option Explicit
If AppPrevInstance() Then   
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding !"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else   
Dim Game,Browser1,Browser2
Game = "%windir%\system32\calc.exe"
Browser1 = "%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
Browser2 = "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
    Do   
        Call Main(Array(Game,Browser1,Browser2))
        Call Pause(1) 'Sleeping for 1 minute
    Loop   
End If   
'**************************************************************************
Sub Main(colProcessPaths)   
    Dim ProcessPath   
    For Each ProcessPath In colProcessPaths     
        CheckProcess(ProcessPath)   
    Next   
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
Sub CheckProcess(ProcessPath)   
    On error resume Next
    Dim Process,objWMIService,colProcesses,wshShell,btn,Timeout,User
    Dim ProcessName : ProcessName = StripProcPath(ProcessPath)   
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Commandline LIKE " & CommandLineLike(ProcessName))
    For Each Process in colProcesses    
        If colProcesses.Count > 0 Then
            Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            User = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
            Timeout = 30 'Call the Popup method with a 30 seconds timeout.
            btn = WshShell.Popup("Hello "& DblQuote(User) & " !" & vbcr &_
            "Your Administrator has requested you to log out of this application after work. " & vbcr &_
            "We have detected you are still using the program : "& DblQuote(ProcessName) & vbcr &_
            "Please press on cancel button if you are still at your machine ?",Timeout,"Question", vbOKCancel + vbQuestion)
            Select Case btn
' Yes button pressed.
            case 1
                Process.Terminate(0)
' No button pressed.
            case 2
                Exit Sub
' Timed out.
            case -1
                Process.Terminate(0)
            End Select
        Else    
            Exit Sub    
        End if 
    Next            
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Sub Pause(Minutes)    
    Wscript.Sleep(Minutes*1000*60)    
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
Function StripProcPath(ProcessPath)   
    Dim arrStr : arrStr = Split(ProcessPath, "\")   
    StripProcPath = arrStr(UBound(arrStr))   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```